# How to make native Android WebRTC voice chat app to work slight with background music on BT headset

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, webrtc, voip

I'm developing an Android VoIP chat app, based on WebRTC native pre-built libraries. It's required to work simultaneously with any background music currently playing using BT headset.

We have the next:

- BT headset connected
- background music playing from any music app, we hear it from the headset earphones

My app initializes it's audio like this:

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

Tried MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION also, but it instantly sets output (both webRTC and music) quality to poor, which is unacceptable. Then, we have two cases:

1) Using

```
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

leads to stopping of music playback.

2) Not using startBluetoothSco() and other lines above - leads to music play fine with the webRTC output, but webRTC uses device's microphone, instead of one on headset

The required behavior is that music continues to play over BT along with the webRTC output and gathering voice from headset microphone. Any ideas how to reach that?

PS. AudioManager.requestAudioFocus() will be definitely needed in future to react to another voice apps interrogations, just wanted to maximally simplify the question. But in the case it matters, I've tried not to use it, or use in the next manner, both don't solve the problem:

```
audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener,
                AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
```

Comment: did u get an answer for this?

Comment: @SnG, no, i didn't.. pretty sure it's just impossible